# Solving $xyy'=2(y+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
y\frac {dy}{dx} = 2\frac {y+1}x \\ 
y\frac {dy}{y+1} = 2\frac {dx}x
$$

Integrating both sides

$$
y-\ln(y+1)= 2\ln x+c\\
e^{y-\ln(y+1)} = e^{\ln x^2+c}\\
\frac {e^y}{e^{\ln y+1}} = e^{\ln x^2}e^c\\
\frac {e^y}{y+1} = cx^2
$$
I'm stuck as I can't figure out how to isolate y here.

Comment: @graydad It should be $d(y - \ln(y+1)) = (1-\frac{1}{y+1})dy = \frac{y}{y+1}dy$.

Comment: There isn't an algebraic way to solve for $y$ unless you are allowed to use lambert function I believe.

Comment: @xsr Please check my edit and use latex the next times you ask questions.

Comment: You found an implicit equation giving the solutions. Is that wrong?

Comment: You don't have to go beyond that then? I thought I had to isolate the y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nicely solved the problem but, as said in comments, you cannot express $y$ as a function of $x$ using elementary functions.

However, for your curiosity, there is an explicit solution in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) which is such that $z=W(z)\, e^{W(z)}$.

Applied to your solution $$\frac {e^y}{y+1} = cx^2$$ the expression becomes $$y=-W\left(\frac{-1}{e\, c\, x^2}\right)-1$$

Lambert function is just fascinating (at least to me !). Euler and Lambert worked together. If you search on this site, you will find a lot of problems solved using it.

Comment: "Euler and Lambert worked together" Any source for this? Compare with: "Euler heard about Lambert's paper in 1764 when Lambert moved from Zurich to Berlin. After some private disputes about the priorities of some related series expansions in 1770/1771, Euler (1783) wrote a paper about Lambert's transcendental equation in which he introduced a special case which reduces to  wa^w=lx, which is nearly the definition of W(x), although Euler proposed defining a function more like -W(-x). ...

Comment: ... Euler considered series solutions in this paper and, in the first paragraph, explicitly quotes Lambert as the one who first considered this equation." http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Comment: @Did. Thanks a lot for these nice informations ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Hmmm... actually I was asking for a source of your statement that "Euler and Lambert worked together". Is there any or is this just some piece of propaganda to associate as closely as possible the name of your hero (Lambert) to the name of Euler, and, consequently, to view Lambert W function as a central mathematical object (something which it is definitely not, if you ask me)?

Comment: @Did. The first one I just found http://cemapre.iseg.ulisboa.pt/archive/preprints/331.pdf More time goes, more, as a physicist, I think (but I can be totally wrong) that Lambert function is a major object.

Comment: There is NOTHING in the paper you linked to, asserting that Euler and Lambert worked together. (For a somewhat more serious source, see http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf.)

Answer (score 1):

This 1st order ODE **is not linear** according to *Elementary Differential Eqns and Boundary Value Problems* by Boyce and DiPrima page 20 because of the term yy'.  I think the method you're using only applies to linear equations. That's why you cant solve.

Comment: There are non-linear, separable ODEs that can be solved algebraically, but many are not.

Comment: Indeed, however this particular method is stated in the given text to only apply to linear ODEs.